# Access mongodb data remotely and render the results on web page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I want to host mongodb database remotely and access the database via querying it and display the results on web page.I came to know that mongodb atlas can be used for hosting it and in order to query the database crest is an API which can be used.But please help me ,whether crest is the thing which will satisfy the requirement that i want to achieve ?If yes then how to proceed with it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Atlas on a personal project and I must say that I am very pleased with it. It's good because you can try it for free and if your project starts to scale you can easily set it up according to your needs. You can also check Azure and AWS options. Regarding the question about Crest: if you need simple logic on your API, you can go for it. But if you want a more complex logic, I would recommend using [**express**](http://expressjs.com/) and [**mongojs**](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) or [**mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/).

Comment: Any good sources if you could recommend to go ahead with express and mongoose ?

Comment: Here you go:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications
https://github.com/KunalKapadia/express-mongoose-es6-rest-api
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/play-by-play-node-web-api-john-papa-sam-artioli